# Remove class only when text blocks are all hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with jquery. I can't find a solution to close this. That is, when I click on the first one and move over the buttons the button block stays fixed on the left instead of going back to the center or prevent the text block from disappearing once activated. I thought of these two solutions, I would be fine with one thing like this:

1. on the second click remove the classes "crossRotate" and "showlink", if I use toggleClass it happens that if I re-click on it happens a problem skips everything
2. at this point that a person clicked over the button always stays without disappearing.

Thank you all for your help and time

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".namebutton").click(function() {
    var div = $("#" + this.value);
    div.toggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    $("#buttons").addClass('crossRotate');
    $("#boxlink, #boxtext").addClass('showlink');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000!important;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}

h5 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.lefteffect {
  transform: translateX(-300px);
}

.testo-descrizione {
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
}

.movimento {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.buttonsclass {
  display: table;
}

.brandname,
.serviceclass,
.b2bclass {
  display: table-row;
}

.tablecell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.content-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.content-33 {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content-3 {
  transition-property: left, right;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#buttons>h5 {
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.crossRotate {
  animation: button 2s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes button {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
}

.brandproject1 {
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
  transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}

.showlink {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 80%;
}

.link {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.text {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 48%;
}

.aParent div {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="height: 900px;">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="buttonsclass" style="height: 600px;margin: auto;">
        <div id="buttons" class="btn tablecell" style="width:90px">
          <h5><input type="button" id="button1" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="Brand" style="width: 100%;"></input>
          </h5>
          <h5><input type="button" id="button2" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="Servizi" style="width: 100%;"> </input>
          </h5>
          <h5><input type="button" id="button3" class="namebutton btn-danger" value="B2B" style="width: 100%;"></input>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="boxlink" class="brandproject1 tablecell">
          <div id="Brand" class="aParent" style="display:none;width: 100%;">
            <div class="link">
              <span><a href="#">1</a></span><br>
              <span><a href="#/">1</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="Servizi" class="aParent" style="display:none;width: 100%;">
            <div class="link">
              <span><a href="#">2</a></span><br>
              <span><a href="#/">2</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="B2B" class="aParent" style="display:none;width: 100%;">
            <div class="link">
              <span><a href="#">3</a></span><br>
              <span><a href="#/">3</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? Currently it is clear from the snippet what happens, but I do not understand what should happen instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it the problem is you are modifying the div for the logic of clicking on different buttons regardless you click on the same button also.

I have modified it to work as you intended. Here is one way to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".namebutton").click(function(){
    $("#" + this.value).toggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    var active = $("#" + this.id).hasClass('active');
    for (var i of $("#buttons>h5>input")) { i.classList.remove('active')}
    if(!active) {    
         $('#buttons').addClass('crossRotate');
         $('#boxlink').addClass('showlink');
        $("#" + this.id).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#buttons').removeClass('crossRotate');
        $('#boxlink').removeClass('showlink');
        $("#" + this.id).removeClass('active');
    }
})})
```

hope this helps.

Comment: that would be: `$("#buttons").toggleClass('crossRotate');` and `$("#boxlink, #boxtext").toggleClass('showlink');`

Comment: ya in the problem he wrote for some reason toggle class is not working. so I wrote this solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The toggleclass doesn't work as long as it was creating a mess with the other elements, if I clicked the second one the class would go away moving the block to the left.

Comment: @bastiag5 Do the other solutions work? Or you are still facing any issues.

Comment: @Rohit Pratap I just tried but the problem was not solved. With your solution if I click the second button everything disappears

Comment: @bastiag5 try the latest code I have updated the answer.